# Javascript does not work after j rendering a view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I dynamically update content to a page using a remote call and a *js.erb file like this:

**add_content.js.erb**

```
$("#new_content").html('<%= j render("content") %>');
```

To render a view like this:
**_content.html.erb**

```
<div class="name">
    <%= @content.name %>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <%= @content.text %>
</div>
```

With an javasript file like this:
**application.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    ...
    $(".name").on('click', function(){
      $(".text").slideToggle();
    });
    ...
})
```

... the javascript slideToggle() is not executed. When I do

```
<%= render("content") %>
```

in any view (without js.erb) everything works as expected and slideToggle() works.
This is just a quick example to keep it simple, it is not related to slideToggle, even alert("...") etc. will not work.

So my question is why is javascript not executed? Is this related to any loading order? Do I need to re-initialize something?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //your code here;
})
```

Comment: Yes, thats how it already looks like. Thanks to your answer I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, For more details please refer this api documentation, http://api.jquery.com/on/

In your **application.js** try like this ....

```
$('#new_content').on('click', '.name', function() {
  $(".text").slideToggle();
});
```

Hope this will work for you ........ Thanks!